# Are the apps written in GLES compatible with the new Vulkan devices

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview, android-graphics

I know this seems like a lame question, but I am currently writing an app and I am not using the Canvas api's, I am using GLSurfaceView and GLES 3.0 for my app. I was worried that with Android Q Vulkan replacing OpenGL ES my app won't be compatible with newer devices.

Answer (score 0):

All Android devices support OpenGLES. I'd be very surprised if Vulkan-only Android devices appear within the next 5 years or so. Apart from anything else, it is pretty easy for a hardware manufacturer with Vulkan compatibility to add OpenGLES support through some sort of compatibility layer like GLOVE.

You can see the distribution of OpenGLES versions [here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards). Note that that page doesn't mention Vulkan at all yet though, but 100% of devices are accounted for in the pie chart at the bottom.